# What is the mechanism of reaction between alcohol and PCl5

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols

Is this one correct? If not why and what is the correct one? [image]

Comment: Strongly Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33675/reaction-of-alcohols-with-pcl5-and-pcl3

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Comment: @Sneha Srikanth Visit Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus_pentachloride and head to the **Reactions** subheading. The mechanism is available there.