# the product form between phosphorus(V) and ethanol

Tags: organic-chemistry

How do I know the main product of the reaction between phosphorus(V) chloride and ethanol?

Answer (score 0):

You could try googling "reaction of PCl5 with alcohols"
In which case you might find this https://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/alcohols/halogen.html  or this  https://crab.rutgers.edu/~alroche/Ch11.pdf
or even this  [Reaction of alcohols with PCl5 and PCl3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33675/reaction-of-alcohols-with-pcl5-and-pcl3)

TL:DR  The product is ethyl chloride and POCl3

Comment: But I was thinking, can't the product formed be chloroethane? Or what else do you think?

Comment: Ethyl chloride and chloroethane are the same thing!