# reaction of PCl5 with alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, halides, nucleophilic-substitution

I am able to think of two possible mechanisms for alcohol+PCl5 here, SN1 and SN2. In SN1, Inversion won't occur whereas, in SN2 inversion will occur. Which of the two is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reaction of alcohols with PCl5 and PCl3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33675/reaction-of-alcohols-with-pcl5-and-pcl3)

Comment: @NilayGhosh thanks for suggestion but that post does not talk about inversion that's why I have posted new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reaction of PCl5 with alcohols leads to inversion. This was demonstrated with Malic Acid by Walden - so the process is sometimes referred to as Walden inversion.
See discussion [here](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/02/10/socl2-and-the-sni-mechanism/) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walden_inversion)