# Stereochemistry of reaction of thionyl chloride and phosphorous pentachloride with alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry

When a secondary alcohol reacts with SOCl2 (or even PCl5), does the reaction proceed via SN2 or SNi?

Comment: see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/171573/reaction-of-pcl5-with-alcohol/171575#171575  for PCl5

Comment: Also see: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69063/if-socl2-reacts-with-alcohols-via-sni-why-doesnt-pocl3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SOCl2 it depends on the reaction conditions- if a base such as pyridine is present the reaction goes with inversion, in the absence of base it goes with retention

Full explanation  [here](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/02/10/socl2-and-the-sni-mechanism/)